# InfoPath cannot call web service when uploaded to Office 365 Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, office365, infopath

Not my normal line of questions, sometimes we've got to be flexible!
I've designed an InfoPath form that I'd like to upload to a Sharepoint site. 
On my form I've got a data source that is consuming the following SOAP service
https://SharepointServer/Site/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL
I call the Operations "GetUserProfileByName" and get various information about the account looking at the form. In preview this works very well. I've got the header saying "Hello Pete" and I'm able to filter lists based on the user's data. However. When it comes to uploading the form to the server, I'm greeted with the following exception:

```
Warning
An error occurred querying a data source.
Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.
HIDE ERROR DETAILS
An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
Log ID:5566

Correlation ID:19df2c9d-a036-2000-3929-0bce8940cf2a
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there limitations due to the way that my account details are being used on SharePoint? If so what's the work around? I'm not a full admin on the server, so I've only got access to a Sandbox site.

Any help greatly appreciated,

Pete

Comment: Could you possibly post the event log entry? That might give use some more information. Besides, I'm curious: why are you using InfoPath? It is a known fact that InfoPath and SharePoint Designer artifacts cause serious issues during deployment cycles.

Comment: Maybe the [Loopback issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861)

Comment: I've now opted for an access app. It seems a lot more stable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is loopback protection. In o365, it cannot be disabled. Stupid though, there are a lot of useful web services available for information. See this link: [Error message when you connect an infopath form to a sharepoint online web service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2674193/error-message-when-you-connect-an-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-online-web-service-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-a-web-service)